# Can not modify DOM elements properties

Tags: javascript, class, dom

Using JS I'm trying to access Document elements to change their classes.

I can

- select them elements and put them into an array, using getElementsByClassName
- apply an event listener to the whole lot
- create a function for that event listener to fire.
- log all alements
- log the click event
- use console.dir to view the document properties

But I can not access to properties like classList, nextElementSibling, etc., which is what I need to do.

if I try

```
event.target.nextElementSibling.classList
```

I get on the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

If inside my function I try something like

```
activeSubmenu = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu--active")[0]
```

and then activeSubmenu.nextElementSibling

I get the same error message about **can not read properties of null.**.If I console log activeSubmenu, I get a piece of HTML.

What I am doing wrong here? Why can't I add, remove and toggle the classes of my elements?

```
const submenues= Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper"));

submenues.forEach(submenu => {
    submenu.addEventListener('click', toggle_submenu);
  });

function toggle_submenu(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(submenu_wrappers);
    console.log(event.target);
    
    let activeSubmenu = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu--active")[0];
    if (activeSubmenu != null) {
        activeSubmenu.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("submenu--active")
    }

}
```

[image: console logs]

Comment: The target doesn't have a next sibling.

Comment: I think that's not a problem here. Variable `submenues` is undefined

Comment: Also please delegate from the nearest static wrapping element: `document.getElementById("wrappersWrapper").addEventListener("click",function(e) { const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.matches(".wrapper")) ... })`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Or at least use newer script: `document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper").forEach(div => {....})`